# Does the Lover stone stack with the spouse rested bonus?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I activate the Lover stone, the bonus says:

> Those under the sign of The Lover always feel a Lover's Comfort. (All skills improve faster.)

This is similar to the bonus you get from sleeping with your spouse (lover's comfort).

Do these affects stack, despite their similar names?

Comment: +1 Good question, I never even thought about this. Also, welcome to the site.

Answer (score 3):

<del>Looking up "Lover's" on the in game console actually shows 2 magic effects called Lover's Comfort: CDA1F and 10D96C.  This implies that while they share the same name, those two effects are considered different, so yes, they should stack with each other with no problems.</del>

Even though there are two versions of the effect that can be seen in the console, the version that is applied from the spouse and the stone are the same (could be a bug), so currently they do **not** stack.

Answer (score 2):

They do not stack. I wanted both so i got the lovers stone. Then, after doing the dirty with my wife, no extra buff. and yes, Jordis the sword maiden is damn good in bed. XD

Answer (score -3):

No but lovers comfort does stack with the mage thief and warrior stones.  So rotate those as needed and rest often